# How to select the text from right to left in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a selection that goes from right to left in the text,this is the code which i am using(it is acheived using mousemove)

```
    getWordAtPoint: function (elem, x, y) {
            if (elem.nodeType == elem.TEXT_NODE) {
   var sel = window.getSelection();
                var range = elem.ownerDocument.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(elem);
                var currentPos = 0;
                var endPos = range.endOffset;
                while (currentPos < endPos) {
                    range.setStart(elem, currentPos);
                    range.setEnd(elem, currentPos + 1);
                    if (range.getBoundingClientRect().left <= x && range.getBoundingClientRect().right >= x &&
                       range.getBoundingClientRect().top <= y && range.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= y) {
                        var ret = range.toString();
                        range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
                        sel.removeAllRanges();
                        sel.addRange(range);
                        range.detach();
                        return (range);
                    }
                    currentPos += 1;
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    var range = elem.childNodes[i].ownerDocument.createRange();
                    range.selectNodeContents(elem.childNodes[i]);
                    if (range.getBoundingClientRect().left <= x && range.getBoundingClientRect().right >= x &&
                       range.getBoundingClientRect().top <= y && range.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= y) {
                        range.detach();
                        return (this._getWordAtPoint(elem.childNodes[i], x, y));
                    } else {
                        range.detach();
                    }
                }
            }
            return (null);
        },
```

Comment: Why you need to select text from right to left and not from left to right? What is wrong that you created this question? Can you create working example of issue?

Comment: i have performed the right to left  selection it is working fine,but left to right selection can be achievable ?kindly reply

Comment: i have acheived by adding the                                                 sel.extend(elem, currentPos + 1); after the                         sel.addRange(range);,now we can able to select the text in both left to right and right to left

Comment: The selection cannot be achieved in IE,how can we achieve the backward selection in Ie